# Is it possible top blacklist someone from using your discord bot/using a certain bot command?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is it possible to disable a certain user from using your bot/using a command (no specific role)?

Comment: You're expected to research and attempt this aswell as show your attempt. This is not a free code writing service. If you wanted a yes or no answer then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your code, you can include `if (message.user.id === 'blacklisted_user_id') return;`